# Return image properties form php

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

i'm developing a sign up form with image upload. Everything is working fine, but when i submit the form with an error and it returns me the erros on the form. Every input saves the previous values by POST except the image.
I would love to know how can i store all image properties to don't loose them if an error is returned!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to directly refill the image input element. But because the image is uploaded to your server nevertheless you should save it to a temporary directory, set a variable with the path to your temporary image on your server in the session and display the image if an error occured, so the user does not need to upload it again.

Comment: That's a interresting option, i'll try it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set the value of input type of file yourself. Your best bet would be to use some sort of an ajax uploader that does not reload the page and lose input values in the first place.

Comment: That's what i was thinking! Thanks for the tip :)